# jquery mobile - javascript not firing after second visit to page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I've come across a strange problem with jQuery mobile - If i have an anchor link to the same page, then the javascript on the page is not run after clicking the link and returning to the same page.

For example (test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('hello');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 1000px">
        <a href="test.html?dosomething=1">test</a>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

... "hello" alert is shown the first time, but after clicking the "test" link (to go back to the same page), the alert doesn't happen.

If I remove the reference to jquery mobile js then it does work as expected, showing "hello".

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile loads internal links via AJAX.

Try changing your anchor to:

```
<a data-ajax="false" href="test.html?dosomething=1">test</a>
```

Documentation - [Linking Pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html):

> Default link behavior: Ajax
>   To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. All this happens automatically by jQuery Mobile.
>
> If the Ajax request is successful, the new page content is added to the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new page is animated into view with a page transition.